# python: преобразовать строку бит ('0', '1') в массив знаковых 32битных чисел

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, struct

Есть срока бит: `'01010101...'`

Подскажите как поэлегантнее преобразовать ее в массив 32битных знаковых чисел?

Решение в лоб работает, но оно некрасивое :)

```
nums = []
for i in range(0, len(bits), 32):
    value = int(bits[i:i + 32], 2)
    nums.append(value if value <= 0x7fffffff else (value - 4294967296))

return nums
```

Что-нибудь из арсенала `numpy` или `struct + bitarray`

Comment: или struct + bitarray - вы дольше будете преобразовывать в другой тип. а под капотом будет примерно тоже

Comment: Да вроде нормально выглядит

Comment: @insolor Так тут это и используется в коде. Остальной код про нарезание строки по 32 символа и прикол со знаковым битом

Comment: @CrazyElf, да, протупил, не увидел, показалось что цикл по самим битам идет.

Comment: @insolor Да, код на вид не шибко интуитивно понятный так то вообще

Comment: просто подумалось что если это все в 1 строку можно сделать с помощью библиотек, то это будет получше

Comment: Преобразование в знаковое число можно сделать так, но это по-моему еще хуже читается: `int.from_bytes((123).to_bytes(4, "little", signed=False), "little", signed=True)`

Comment: А вообще я когда-то подобное преобразование в знаковое просто в отдельную функцию вынес и не парился: https://github.com/dfint/dfrus/blob/74a0815d1801a9ea6ecff7a311591a4ac92b0e84/dfrus/binio.py#L61

Answer (score 4):

Если на "голом" Python, то я бы сделал в два отдельных этапа: преобразование битов в байты, потом преобразование байт в знаковые инты. Получится длиннее, но без вычитаний магических чисел:

```
def bits_to_bytes(bits: str):
    for i in range(0, len(bits), 8):
        yield int(bits[i : i + 8], 2)


def bytes_to_ints(b: bytes):
    for i in range(0, len(b), 4):
        yield int.from_bytes(b[i : i + 4], "big", signed=True)


import random

n = 10  # В итоге должно получиться 10 чисел
bits = "".join(random.choices("01", k=8 * 4 * n))
print(bits)

bts = bytes(bits_to_bytes(bits))
print(bts)

ints = list(bytes_to_ints(bts))
print(ints)
```

Пример вывода:

```
10010011000101110011111000111100100110111110011001001001110111100110110001101000011010011011101011001011011110110010101010000110110001010000000010100100011010111101110101100111100110100011111001111010101110110011111100011100000110000011001110111000010010011111010011101010110101110110100011000000001101111000010110100101
b'\x93\x17><\x9b\xe6I\xdelhi\xba\xcb{*\x86\xc5\x00\xa4k\xddg\x9a>z\xbb?\x1c\x183\xb8I\xf4\xea\xd7h\xc07\x85\xa5'
[-1827193284, -1679406626, 1818782138, -881120634, -989813653, -580412866, 2059091740, 406042697, -185936024, -1070103131]
```

Comment: почему "little" ?  int(х, 2) это "big"

Comment: Да, согласен, тут big, сейчас поправлю. По привычке везде автоматом little ставлю.

Answer (score 4):

как вариант

```py
def f(x):
    return np.packbits(np.fromiter(x, dtype='b'), bitorder='big').view(dtype='>i4')
```

```
>>> x = f'{-987654321 & 0xffffffff:032b}{1234567890:032b}'
>>> x
'1100010100100001100101110100111101001001100101100000001011010010'
>>> f(x)
array([-987654321, 1234567890], dtype=int32)
```

Answer (score 3):

Голый питон без циклов. Строка переводится в целое число, целое число в массив байт, массив байт в массив четырёхбайтовых целых, массив четырёхбайтовыx целых в массив целых. По пути порядок значений перевернулся:

```
import array


def bits_to_ints(bits):
    assert len(bits) % 32 == 0
    i = int(bits, 2)
    b = i.to_bytes(len(bits) // 8, 'little', signed=False)
    a = array.array('i')
    a.frombytes(b)
    return list(a[::-1])


bits = (
    '10000000000000000000000000000000' # -2147483648
    '11111111111111111111111111110110' #         -10
    '11111111111111111111111111111111' #          -1
    '00000000000000000000000000000000' #           0
    '00000000000000000000000000000010' #           2
    '00000000000000000000000000010100' #          20
    '01111111111111111111111111111111' #  2147483647
)

print(bits_to_ints(bits))
```

> ```
> $ python restore_ints.py
> [-2147483648, -10, -1, 0, 2, 20, 2147483647]
> ```

Алгоритм линейный:

```
 число   время
 бит     работы (c)

 10^5    0.0003
 10^6    0.0030
 10^7    0.0291
 10^8    0.2974
 10^9    2.9931
```

**P.S.** Это извращение. Если вы понимаете почему в конце нужно перевернуть массив - вы молодец.

**P.P.S** Последнее преобразование в `list` можно не делать. Целые в `array` такие же целые как и любые другие.